# Evaluate(NormSInv(rand())) in VBA throws an error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a standard normal random variable in VBA, using the following: `Evaluate(NormSInv(rand()))`. But I get an error saying that `rand()` is not a defined function, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Evaluate` expects a formula string:

```
Evaluate("NormSInv(rand())")
```

Comment: Damn.. That was close :D

Comment: haha you two literally answered at the same time... ah tough decision

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("=NORMSINV(RAND())")
```